# How to check the count of xml nodes and delete if over 10 using php

Tags: php, xml, forms, count, nodes

I have created upload a form that adds names to xml but i want to check the number of name nodes and if 10 delete the 10th one and add a new one to the top.

my html is

```
<form name="form" id="form" action="insert.php" method="post" >    
<label for="name">Name:</label> <br />  
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> <br />    
<button type="submit" id="button">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

and insert.php is

```
<?php 

header('Location:index.php'); 

$xmldoc = new DOMDocument(); 
$xmldoc->load('names.xml'); 

$Name = $_POST['name']; 

$root = $xmldoc->firstChild;

$fileName = $xmldoc->createElement('name'); 

$root->appendChild($fileName); 

$newText1 = $xmldoc->createTextNode($Name);

$fileName->appendChild($newText1); 

$xmldoc->save('names.xml');  

?>
```

which creates names.xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<item>
<name>Name1</name>
<name>Name2</name>
<name>Name3</name>
<name>Name4</name>
<name>Name5</name>
<name>Name6</name>
<name>Name7</name>
<name>Name8</name>
<name>Name9</name>
<name>Name10</name>
<name>Name11</name>
etc.

</item>
```

but what i need to do is count the name nodes if over 10 delete them.

How would i go about doing this?

Comment: "Delete them" delete them how? The old or new name? Do you want there to be a rotating window of names? You need to figure out what you want before asking for help. What was your solution which didn't work?

Comment: if node.length is > 10 delete the remove nodes after the 10th one. I am using jquery ajax to load the xml file and only want the last 10 to be shown. I know how to achieve this with jquery but i dont want it to keep loading an xml file that has 1000s of names stored in it and will take a while to load.  What i would like is when the xml is loaded it counts the name nodes if node.length < 10 do nothing is node.length > 10 delete the last node stored or everything after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<item>
    <name>Name1</name>
    <name>Name2</name>
    <name>Name3</name>
    <name>Name4</name>
    <name>Name5</name>
    <name>Name6</name>
    <name>Name7</name>
    <name>Name8</name>
    <name>Name9</name>
    <name>Name10</name>
    <name>Name11</name>
    <name>Name12</name>
    <name>Name13</name>
    <name>Name14</name>
</item>
');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// use: //name[position() > 10]    to remove nodes after the tenth
foreach ($xpath->query('//name[position() < count(//name) - 9]') as $nameNode) {
    $nameNode->parentNode->removeChild($nameNode);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

**Output**:

```
<item>
  <name>Name5</name>
  <name>Name6</name>
  <name>Name7</name>
  <name>Name8</name>
  <name>Name9</name>
  <name>Name10</name>
  <name>Name11</name>
  <name>Name12</name>
  <name>Name13</name>
  <name>Name14</name>
</item>
```

Comment: Bingo! Thats the business! :-)

Answer (score 0):

PHP's DOM classes have methods for [`RemoveChild`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php) and [`getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php).

Between them, these methods should give you what you want. Something like this should do the trick:

```
$names = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('name');

if($names->length > 10) {
    $firstname = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0);
    $removedname = $xmlDoc->removeChild($firstname);
}
```

(note: not tested it yet, though, so you might have to tweak it a bit!)